# Append an empty row in dataframe using pandas : criteria best performance

Tags: python, pandas

- Requirement : Add add empty row to dataframe
- Constraint : Performance

```
# dataframe is onedf
 temp_false_list = []
for xray in range(onedf.shape[1]):
       temp_false_list.append(np.nan)
onedf.loc[len(onedf)] = temp_false_list # this line takes 90% of time
```

- this works and appends a empty row to the dataframe but when checked with %lprun -f the loc assignment operation is taking 90 % of the time
- I have to perform more 3k time the same operation(on other similar 3k data frames)
- Taking only performance into consideration how can this improve ?

  [image]

Comment: whats the criteria to append an empty row ? If it is, why dont you create a temp dataframe with one row of data and just concat to existing dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append operations in pandas are costly. What you can do is to convert the dataframe into the list of dictionary and then append temp to the python list of the dictionary.
After processing, convert the list of dictionaries back to the dataframe.

for example, let's say I have got a dataframe onedf like this. -

```
|   | product  | old_price | new_price | final_price |
|---|----------|-----------|-----------|-------------|
| 0 | product1 | 10        | 20.0      | 10.0        |
| 1 | product2 | 20        | 10.0      | -10.0       |
| 2 | product3 | 30        | NaN       | NaN         |
| 3 | product4 | 40        | NaN       | NaN         |
```

Now, you want to append rows into this so convert it into the list of dictionary first-

```
dict1 = onedf.to_dict(orient='records')
```

This will give output like this -

```
[{'product': 'product1',
  'old_price': 10,
  'new_price': 20.0,
  'final_price': 10.0},
 {'product': 'product2',
  'old_price': 20,
  'new_price': 10.0,
  'final_price': -10.0},
 {'product': 'product3',
  'old_price': 30,
  'new_price': nan,
  'final_price': nan},
 {'product': 'product4',
  'old_price': 40,
  'new_price': nan,
  'final_price': nan}]
```

Now, just create an empty dict matching the same format and append. It'll be a lot faster to do.

```
import numpy as np
temp_false_list = [np.nan for _ in range(4)]
temp_dict = dict(zip(onedf.columns.values,temp_false_list))
# {'product': nan, 'old_price': nan, 'new_price': nan, 'final_price': nan}
```

append it to dict we've created before -

```
dict1.append(temp_dict)
```

Finally, convert dict1 back to the dataframe.

```
onedf_new = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work for 3k dataframes or not. I thought you're doing the same process multiple times for the same dataframe :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any details about the input dataframe, I answer based on my assumptions. You could try to use `pandas.DataFrame.reindex()` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # dataframe is onedf
    onedf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["c0", "c1"])
    onedf = onedf.reindex(onedf.index.tolist() + list(range(0, 20)))
    print(onedf)
```

Result:

```
     c0   c1
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN
12  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN
14  NaN  NaN
15  NaN  NaN
16  NaN  NaN
17  NaN  NaN
18  NaN  NaN
19  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I have amended the question for better clarity . Please check,