# Does append take longer if the file is larger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to keep appending data to a .csv file and I was wondering if appending data to it becomes slower as the .csv increases in size?

In case it matters I am using pandas `to_csv()` function to append a dataframe to the .csv.

Comment: Have you tried timing it?

Comment: Are you loading CSV to the dataframe and then appending multiple rows? If yes, then are you loading the CSV to the dataframe once or again and again?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I could but wouldn't that be effected by possible other processes running on the machine? I assume there is some general knowledge on if the size of a file effects the time it takes to append data.

Comment: @Nk03 No. A dataframe is created containing approx. 100.000 rows that is appended to the .csv for later analyses.

Comment: Try running a bunch of timing tests on DFs of increasing size and see if the time increases linearly or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068584/append-an-empty-row-in-dataframe-using-pandas-criteria-best-performance/67068785#67068785 refer to this once

Comment: @Nk03 that refers to appending to a dataframe not a .csv, I doubt the same principles are involved.

Comment: Can you please add the code ? How're you appending the dataframe to CSV file?